# local file reading from extjs without submit button

Tags: javascript, java, excel, extjs

I have an excel sheet which contains multiple columns with data. Along with that a column it contains file path.

When I upload the excel sheet to an **extjs** grid, I want to read blob data from local system based on file path column before submit to database.

I don't have a form, I need to get data when I click on submit button from grid. I have tried reading a file in java but it is reading from server system instead of local system. How can we read local system data from excel sheet. How can I do it in JAVA?[pls find attached img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72jrU.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. Also do you mean JAVA or JavaScript?